# Listening to only one phone state

Tags: android

I am using the PhoneState Action in my Android app, but there is a problem, Wen I get the number from an incoming call during ringing state, it works fine but after I pick the call my BroadCastReceiver crashes because the intent bundle is null coz there is no number to fetch.

How do I make sure I am listening to only to the Ringing state and not any other weird stuff:

Here is my code:

```
package com.messageHider;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class incomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        String number=bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        dbConnection connection=new dbConnection(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db=connection.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.query(dbConnection.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, dbConnection.CONTACT+"=?",new String[]{number}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count=cursor.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".messageHider"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".sms"/>
    <activity android:name=".viewsms"/>
    <activity android:name=".hiddenMessages"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".viewContacts">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".smsService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".smsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".smsSentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".incomingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation about [`EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER):

> The lookup key used with the
>   ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast
>   for a String containing the incoming
>   phone number. Only valid when the new
>   call state is RINGING.

This means your code should be:

```java
public class incomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        if( bundle != null ){
             String number=bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
             if( number != null ){
                 dbConnection connection=new dbConnection(context);
                 SQLiteDatabase db=connection.getReadableDatabase();
                 Cursor cursor=db.query(dbConnection.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, 
                                        dbConnection.CONTACT+"=?",
                                        new String[]{number}, 
                                        null, null, null);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 int count=cursor.getCount();
                 Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure you listen only to the Ringing state by looking at the state in the intent's extra at your onReceive:

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
    // the phone switched to the Ringing state
} else {
    // the phone switched to another state
}
```

See an example at the Android cookbook at: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1109